# Password always resetting on the first user only [Laravel]?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend

Im new to laravel and i decided to make a little project to learn a bit and im trying to make a password reset function following this tutorial but the code seems to always update the first user no matter what. Even if user2@gmail.com tries to reset password, the password resets for user1@gmail.com.
Here is the code :

## PasswordReset

```php
public function forgotPassword(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->get();
        if (count($user) > 0) {
            $token = Str::random(40);
            $domain = URL::to('/');
            $url = $domain.'/reset-Password?token='.$token;
            $data['url'] = $url;
            $data['email'] = $request->email;
            $data['title'] = "Password Reset";
            $data['body'] = "Please click the link below to reset ur password";

            Mail::send(
                'forgetPasswordMail',
                ['data' => $data],
                function ($message) use ($data) {
                    $message->to($data['email'])->subject($data['title']);                            
                }
            );

            $datetime = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            PasswordReset::updateOrCreate(
                ['email' => $request->email],
                [
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'token' => $token,
                    'created_at' => $datetime
                ]
            );

            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'msg' => 'Password Reset Sent']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'User not Found']);
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}

public function resetPasswordLoad(Request $request)
{
    $resetData = PasswordReset::where('token', $request->token)->first();
    if ($resetData) {
        $user = User::where('email', $resetData->email)->first();
        if ($user) {
            return view('resetPassword', ['user' => $user]);
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'error404']);
}
            
public function resetPassword(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'user_id' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    if ($user) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();
        PasswordReset::where('email', $user->email)->delete();

        return "<h1>Password reset successfully</h1>";
    } else {
        return "<h1>Error: User not found</h1>";
    }
}
```

## view

```xml
@if($errors->any())
  <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif

<center>
  <form method="POST" action="/reset-Password">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">  
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</center>
```

I tried switching between using the token and email to authenticate but that just made the code a mess.

Comment: You have some issues in your code, one of them critical. You're changing the password of the user using the content of the parameter `request->user_id`. This opens a door for anyone to just change the value into anything and ultimately update the password of any user.

Comment: Are you sure the correct email is being passed to `PasswordReset::forgotPassword`? try doing `dd($request->email)` there ans see if it shows you different values when you try `user1@gmail.com`and `user2@gmail.com`. Do these users have the same `id` in the database? That shouldn't be possible if `ìd` is a pk, but check anyways.

Comment: When you get this working, as part of the learning exercise, I advise you to read the vendor code to understand how laravel does it behind the scenes.

Comment: yes so the id isnt the same since it auto increments, but now i see that the value being passed to the hidden input 'user_id' is 1 instead of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new in Laravel too. I started with it 3 months ago. I have to say, I was to much for me to do whole reset password logic on my own at this stage.

So in created new temp project with Breeze (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade), and I tried to understand the reset password by debugging it step by step via xdebug.

Then I implemented same logic in my project and it is working like a charm.

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    if ($status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
        return back()->with('success', __($status));
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => [trans($status)],
    ]);
}

public function resetPassword(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'token' => ['required'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
    ]);

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function ($user) use ($request) {
            $user->forceFill([
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
            ])->save();

            event(new PasswordReset($user));
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $status == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? redirect()->route('login')->with('success', __($status))
                : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                        ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
}
public function resetPasswordLoad(Request $request): View
{
    return view('auth.reset-password', ['request' => $request]);
}
```

View reset-password.blade.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.store') }}">
    @csrf
        <div class="mx-auto d-block w-100">
            <p class="login-form-title py-3">{{__('login.reset_password_header')}}</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Password Reset Token -->
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $request->route('token') }}">

        <div class="form-floating my-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="{{old('email', $request->email)}}">
            <label for="email">{{__('user.email')}}</label>
            @error('email')
                <span class="error-message">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating my-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{old('password')}}" required>
            <label for="password">{{__('user.password')}}</label>
            @error('password')
                <span class="error-message">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating my-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Repeat your password" value="{{old('password_confirmation')}}" required>
            <label for="password_confirmation">{{__('user.repeat_your_password')}}</label>
            @error('password_confirmation')
                <span class="error-message">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <!-- Submit button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4 w-100">{{__('generic.submit')}}</button>
        <div class="text-center">
            <p><a href="{{route('login')}}">{{__('login.back_to_login')}}</a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

View: forgot-password.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('password.email')}}">
    @csrf
        <div class="mx-auto d-block w-100">
            <p class="login-form-title py-3">{{__('login.forgot_password_header')}}</p>
            <p class="login-form-subtitle">
                {{__('login.to_reset_your_password')}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating my-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="{{old('email')}}">
            <label for="email">{{__('user.email')}}</label>
            @error('email')
                <span class="error-message">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <!-- Submit button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4 w-100">{{__('generic.submit')}}</button>
        <div class="text-center">
            <p><a href="{{route('login')}}">{{__('login.back_to_login')}}</a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```